# missing m2 repository after a docker build

Tags: maven, docker, dockerfile

If I run a `docker build` that pulls down maven dependencies into an .m2 repository, that doesn't persist in the image.

So if I then try to *i)* tty into a running container, my `~/.m2/repository` directory will be empty. Or *ii)* if I build another image on top of the first, those deps will have to be downloaded again.

Contents of my `Dockerfile` are here.

```
FROM maven:3.5.0-jdk-8-alpine

RUN apk update \
    && apk add ca-certificates \
    && update-ca-certificates \
    && apk add openssl \
               bash \
               git

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN mvn compile
```

I'm sure this is some simple detail of docker that I'm not understanding. Anyone have any insights there?

Comment: A docker build does not pull any kind of Maven dependencies into `$HOME/.m2/repository`...only if you run some kind of Maven build inside the container which means they will not being persistent...by definition of the container....If you like to get your `$HOME/.m2/repository ` to be enhanced with the dependencies you have to mount that as a volume into your container...which means the running process inside the container writes into it.

Comment: can you share the details of your dockerfile ?

Comment: @vegiops Sure, added.

Answer (score 1):

@khmarbaise Yes, you're right. I just had to specify a `VOLUME /root/.m2/repository` entry in my Dockerfile. I also removed cached containers and volumes, just to be sure. And sire enough, the repository is there, as I expect.

So my Dockerfile now looks something like this. I didn't have a full grokking of docker volumes. But that all makes sense now. Thanks.

```
FROM maven:3.5.0-jdk-8-alpine

RUN apk update \
    && apk add ca-certificates \
    && update-ca-certificates \
    && apk add openssl \
               bash \
               git

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
VOLUME /root/.m2/repository

RUN mvn compile
```